# Controlling what kind of DMA addresses are given by dma_pool_alloc

Tags: linux-kernel, arm, dma

I have an ARM platform with two kinds of RAM. There's some SDRAM and internal SRAM. The USB controller on the platform needs a DMA address residing on the internal SRAM only. At the moment, I'm using a generic driver which gets usable DMA addresses from calling `dma_pool_alloc`.

Is there a way to tell the kernel to only give the USB driver DMA addresses that are on the internal SRAM rather than SDRAM?

Answer (score 0):

You must use a separate allocator. For example [iram_alloc.c](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/arm/mach-imx/iram_alloc.c) is used by **IMX** devices to get memory from internal SRAM.  You may have to over-allocate to get memory that is on a boundary required by the DMA controller.

If memory goes into the generic kernel pools, there is no way to differentiate.  Typically, if memory has special properties, a platform will provide alternate means to access it.

Comment: [DMA-API-HOWTO.txt](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/DMA-API-HOWTO.txt) and [DMA-API.txt](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/DMA-API.txt) maybe helpful to others looking here.